# Threads in arrayList don't know interrupt

Tags: java, multithreading

Threads are stored in an `ArrayList` so that they can dynamically be set later on by their name. There are a lot of examples on the Internet, all about this, but I do not work, so the selected thread does not stop.
What can my fault be?

```
public class Szal {
    static ArrayList<MyThread> myThread;
    static String[] names;

    public Szal() {
        myThread = new ArrayList<MyThread>();
        names = new String[]{"EZ", "AZ"};

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            MyThread t = new MyThread(names[i]);
            myThread.add(t);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Szal();

        Thread[] thread = new Thread [Thread.activeCount ()];
        int m = Thread.enumerate (thread);
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            System.out.println (thread[i].getName());
        }

        // Why is this not working?
        for (Thread t : myThread) {
            if (t.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("EZ")) {
                t = Thread.currentThread();
                t.interrupt();
                myThread.remove(t);
            }
        }

        Thread[] threads = new Thread [Thread.activeCount ()];
        int c = Thread.enumerate (threads);
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            System.out.println (threads[i].getName());
        }
    }

    class MyThread extends Thread {
        public MyThread(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which thread is being interrupted here ?

Comment: Why are you doing `t= Thread.currentThread();` ?? Even after you will fix it and interrupt `t` you need the thread to be in an interuptibel state for it to actually do something other then just setting the flag. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//this why not working???
for(Thread t : myThread){
    if(t.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("EZ")){
        t= Thread.currentThread();
        t.interrupt();
        myThread.remove(t);
    }
}
```

You iterate over all threads in the list and iterrupt yourself as soon as you reach the one with the name `EZ`. I'm not sure if that's what you actually planned to do, your question sounded more like you wanted to interrupt the EZ-Thread. In that case you should omit the line `t = Thread.currentThread()`.

You haven't explained what exactly you mean with "not working", I assume that you mean that the thread you interrupted still continues to run. That's because, none of the threads is actually performing an operation that is checking the fact if it's interrupted.

You might change your MyThread-implementation this way:

```
class MyThread extends Thread{

    public MyThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        }
        catch(InterrutedException ie) {
            // leads to the end of the thread
        }
    }
}
```

or alternatively

```
while(!interrupted()){

}
```

Oh, and wait a bit between interrupting and outputting all Threads. Starting and shutting down threads is a complex task that takes some time. So even with fully functional code that reliably shuts down your Thread, the interrupted one might still show up as active if you list all threads immediately afterwards.